# Bootstrap 3: div wrap row in col display incorrectly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My html structure as below:

```
<main class="main col col-sm-6" role="main" style="border:1px solid yellow;">
  <div class="mycontainer" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="row" style="border:1px solid blue;">
     <!--Place here some colums-->
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

See here for more details: http://www.bootply.com/1r7RpM70uM

Why the left and right borders (red borders) of "mycontainer" display inside "row" borders (blue borders)? why it's not wrap "row" borders? and how to fix this?

Note: I need "mycontainer" wraps "row"

Comment: what do you mean by "not wrap 'row' border"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default css of bootstrap `.row` has a `margin:0 -15px;` so to be able to override it, add
`margin:0;` to your row. But it will decrease the space inside of your column.

### [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DJPKj93DZM)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your requirement here. I have made a new fork for you to see if this is what you want ?
http://www.bootply.com/AfOgKF2KVw

All I have done is to remove row style from inner div and applied to the container div :

Comment: hey, thanks but it's not fits my purpose. I want "mycontainer" wraps "row". Is there any other way?